# Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: EXPORT FAILED

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode10.1

My CLI info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: 2.0.0 
ios-sim version: 7.0.0 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

I have added push notification in my ionic project which is running properly in `Xcode 9.4` after I updated `Xcode 10.1` and open my project in Xocde 10.1. When I run the ionic build ios command in CLI I got the following error in my CLI. My app is running on device but push notification is not working.

```
2018-12-24 15:54:32.585 xcodebuild[1441:238192] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/dl/T/app_2018-12-24_15-54-32.584.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: "app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 "app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,app.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/app/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/app/platforms/ios/build/device
```

I have removed `iOS platform` and added again and check all the Development, Distribution certificates, push notification provisioning profile and added again in my project still getting this error.
project is running properly in `Xcode 9.4` with push Notification but it is not working in `Xcode 10.1`.
I don't find the exact rootCause it's regarding Xcode version or any certificates issue?
Can anyone help me? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I haven't find any solutions. Can you help me?

Comment: Hello, I tried all the scenario but didn't find any solution. Anyone help me to find the solution for this?

Comment: `"app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.`  Looks important.

Comment: I am facing the above issue only for Xcode 10.1 as I have mentioned. I want to know the reason behind the issue. All the certificates and provisioning profiles are already added and app is already running on App store.

Comment: But does the provisioning profile contain the Push Notifications feature as per the error message?

Comment: didn't find any solution for now but if you want to create ipa you can use lower xcode version 8.x as per your os

Comment: @trojanfoe Push notification feature is already added and its working fine with Xcode 9.4 version and its also added for Xcode 10.1